# Generate pfx certificate from pem rsa

Tags: certificate, openssl, dkim, rsa

I have a PEM RSA private key generated with opendkim:

```
# dkim-genkey -t -s code001 -d domain.com
```

and for use it with exchange, i need to convert it to pfx with this command:

```
# openssl pkcs12 -export -in code001.private -nodes -out code001.pfx -nokeys
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
4192275:error:0D0C6070:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_pack:encode error:asn_pack.c:170:
```

but i receive this error, and i don't know if this is the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails because `code001.private` only contains an RSA key, while pkcs12 expects a certificate to go with it. In addition, as said by Stephane, the -nokeys option will cause openssl to skip the private key.

You can generate a certificate with

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key code001.private -out code001.pem
```

and fill in the interactive questions, then generate the pfx with

```
cat code001.private code001.pem |openssl pkcs12 -export -out code001.pfx
```

Comment: Works perfect, i had this problem several days, really thanks

Answer (score 1):

the `-nokeys` parameter will cause OpenSSL not to include any private key in the output and the `-nodes`parameter will ask it not to encrypt any private key. This is not going to result in a usable PKCS#12 file anyway.

Try it with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in code001.private -out code001.pfx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt